# How to make a dynamic string?

Tags: c, string, dynamic

I am trying to make a program that I think should be simple. I want to ask for a word and store it in a vector with its right size (more `\n` logically). To do this, the program asks the user to write a word ending with a `.`. Then, the program reads letter by letter and stores the letters in a string that is created dynamically as the letters are being read.

```c
int main() {
   int i = 0, tam = 0;
   char *cad = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
   char c;

   printf("word: ");

   while (c != '.') {
       scanf("%c", c);
       cad[i] = c;
       i++;
       cad = realloc(cad, (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
   }
   cad[i] = '\0';

   for (i = 0; cad[i] == '\0'; i++) {
       tam++;
   }
   printf("tam: %d\n", tam);

   return 0;
}
```

I have made this but I think that it doesn't do anything useful

Comment: To be pedantic: In C, we don't have vectors.

Comment: yeah I know @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio

Comment: sorry it was an error @bruno

Comment: you missed to initialize *i*

Comment: i is not initialized to 0.

Comment: now yes @TomKuschel

Comment: the computation of *tam* has no sense, you have *i* .. supposing you initialized it to 0

Comment: And you missed "&" in the scanf

Comment: and you missed to initialize *c*  too for the first loop

Comment: @bruno i dont know how initialize c for the first loop

Comment: @sonlas10 initialize it with anything except '.'

Answer (score 1):

It is simpler to use `getchar()` to read individual bytes from the file. Also check for allocation and reallocation failures:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int len = 0;
    char *cad, *new_cad;
    int c;

    printf("word: ");

    cad = malloc(len + 1);
    if (cad == NULL) {
        printf("memory allocation failure\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '.') {
        cad[len] = (char)c;
        len++;
        new_cad = realloc(cad, len + 1);
        if (new_cad == NULL) {
            printf("memory allocation failure\n");
            free(cad);
            return 1;
        }
        cad = new_cad;
    }
    cad[len] = '\0';

    printf("tam: %d, string: %s\n", len, cad);
    free(cad);

    return 0;
}
```

Reallocating the dynamic string one byte at a time is inefficient but implementing a better strategy is an optimisation. First focus on correctness, only optimize if needed as proven by careful benchmarking.

Answer (score 0):

Made all the changes, this should give you the desired output.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
   int i = 0, tam = 0;
   char *cad = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
   char c = 'l';

   printf("word: ");

   while(c != '.'){
       c= getchar();
       cad[i] = c;
       i++;
       cad = realloc(cad, (i + 1)*sizeof(char));
   }
   cad[i] = '\0';

/*
As pointed out by Bruno, this for loop just calculates the length of the char array, so commented this
for(i = 0; cad[i] == '\0'; i++){
    tam++;
}
printf("tam: %d\n", tam);
*/
printf("tam: %d\n", i);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: please replace `scanf("%c", &c);` by a simple `getchar`and why about to check EOF ? and also proposes to remove the loop about *tam* because it is useless and the length of the string is already known (warning the code was edited you end loop is wrong)

Comment: does it works for you?  because it doesn't work for me

Comment: @bruno OP wants the no of characters = '\n' right? So, why to remove the last loop

Comment: Sorry @bruno just saw it. Will remove it.

Comment: `c` must have type `int` for proper `EOF` checking.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make a dynamic string?

Read *carefully* a book such as [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), then refer to a good [C reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Read the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) and debugger (perhaps [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). Of course, read with attention the documentation of *every* function (e.g. `scanf`) that you are using.

```
 while(c != '.'){
   scanf("%c", c);
   cad[i] = c;
   i++;
   cad = realloc(cad, (i + 1)*sizeof(char));
 }
```

### Your code above is both wrong and inefficient.

It is wrong, since you use [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (wrongly: should be `scanf("%c", &c)` but you really want to use [getchar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar)) and [realloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) but don't handle their failure case

It is inefficient, because you probably don't want to reallocate the string at every loop. Unless you are very tight on memory (in practice, improbably) you should consider using `realloc` only once in a while (since `realloc` is probably a costly operation). You could for example first `malloc` a buffer of 128 bytes, and `realloc` it only when needed (when you did read 127 bytes) to e.g. newsize=3*oldsize/2  (so the second time to 192 bytes, etc...)

And if you compiled with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) you'll get useful warnings.

Comment: @BasileStarykevitch I guess you also missed the ''&" in scanf

Comment: It is even more wrong because `c` is uninitialized and `scanf("%c", c);` should be `scanf("%c", &c);`

Answer (score 0):

Two bits of advice:

1. `realloc` is a relatively expensive operation, and you really don't want to do it for each character.  A common technique is to double the buffer size as necessary - this will minimize the total number of `realloc` calls.  You may wind up with some internal fragmentation, but on average it shouldn't be too bad.
2. If `realloc` cannot extend the buffer, it will return `NULL` and leave the original buffer in place.  Thus, you do *not* want to assign the result of `realloc` back to the original pointer without checking it first, otherwise you could lose your reference to the previously allocated memory.

It would also be better to use `getchar` or `fgetc` for reading the input as opposed to `scanf`.

So:

```
#define START_SIZE 2
...
size_t size = START_SIZE;  // tracks the size of the buffer
size_t length = 0;         // tracks the length of the string in the buffer
char *cad = calloc( size, sizeof *cad ); 

/**
 * **ALWAYS** check the result of a malloc, calloc, or realloc call.
 */
if ( !cad )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "Couldn't allocate initial buffer, bailing out here...\n" );
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

for ( int c = getchar(); c != '.' && c != EOF; c = getchar() )
{
  /**
   * First, make sure we still have room in our buffer (accounting for the
   * zero terminator) - if we don't, double it.
   */
  if ( length + 1 == size )
  {
    char *tmp = realloc( cad, sizeof *cad * ( 2 * size ) );
    if ( !tmp )
    {
      fprintf( stderr, "realloc failed, exiting loop with what we've read so far\n" );
      break;
    }      
    cad = tmp;
    size *= 2;
  }
  cad[length++] = c;
  cad[length] = 0;   // terminate the string as we go
}
```

Comment: Interesting alternative, but there is a bug: the string is uninitialized if the user types `.` as the first character... *terminating the string as you go* is neither needed nor sufficient.

Comment: @chqrlie: Fixed initialization by using `calloc` instead of `malloc`.  Keeping the terminate as you go, so the string will be properly terminated in the event the `realloc` fails.

Comment: While this fixes the problem, it is not entirely consistent as the initial block will be fully initialized to all bits zero, but the reallocated blocks will have uninitialized bytes at the end.

Comment: `buf[length++] = c;` must be `cad[length++] = c;` and same for `buf[length] = 0;   // terminate the string as we go` which is also better placed after the `for` rather than inside

Comment: a final *realloc* after the `for` to reduce the size to the used one can help too, the buffer allocated size if in 2^n which is quickly very long